# Assign a view template based on a variable in your data?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm using backbone and marionette and i'd like to render the views based on a variable in the data. this.model.template I was thinking could pull from my data (returning myTemplate and myOtherTemplate) and then I could do some manipulation in the render function but it's not working. Any suggestions?. Can the view be made aware of the model?

```
var graph = [{
    nodeName: "1st level item",
    template: "myTemplate",
    nodes: [{
        nodeName: "2nd level item",
        template: "myOtherTemplate"
    }]
}];


TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = this.model.nodes;
    },
    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
        collectionView.$("li:first").append(itemView.el);
    },
    render: function(){
        var that = this;
        console.log('Loading template name: ' + name + ' template: ' + this.template + ' data: ' + this.model.template);
        TemplateManager.get(this.template, function(template){
            var html = $(template).tmpl();
            that.$el.html(html);
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your question is.  Can the view be made aware of the model?  Of course :-)  Just do: `this.model` to reference a view's model from within it.  Beyond that though I don't get what you are asking.

Comment: this.model.template returns undefined for me :(

Comment: this.model will be whatever model you passed in to your view.  So somewhere in your code you must have `new TreeView({...`; inside that elipsis you can define a model, like so: `new TreeView{model: new Backbone.Model(graph)`

Comment: All that being said, models are generally supposed to represent data; your template really belongs as a property of your view rather than of your model.

Answer (score 2):

How are you initializing the view?

The view generally expects that the model is a Backbone model. When accessing model attribute, you should use `mymodel.get('attributeName')`. The individual attributes are not available directly on the model. They're available in `mymodel.attributes` (for example, `mymodel.attributes.template`) but `attributes` should not be used directly except for debugging because how attributes are stored and accessed may change in the future or be changed by various plugins if you use any.

Also note that in most cases you shouldn't need to override the `render` method. Instead, take a look at `beforeRender` and `onRender`.